# Permission Error 13 when running a plotly scatter plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I'm following a MOOC and got stuck at this part of the code where I'm getting the following error:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'scatter.html'

```py
import numpy as np
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go

np.random.seed(42)

random_x = np.random.randint(1,101,100)
random_y = np.random.randint(1,101,100)

data = [go.Scatter(x=random_x, y=random_y, mode='markers')]

pyo.plot(data, filename='scatter.html')
```

I'm not entirely sure what is causing this, but I've been having so many problems ever since trying to work on this project in a virtual environment within VScode.Does anyone know what is causing this error? Unfortunately, I'm at a lost and cannot find a solution online.

Comment: I tested your code and it works on my computer, so the problem is not your code, can you give more details about the version of python, numpy, plotly you are using, the operating system ?.

Comment: I've tried this code on another laptop and it works, so it must be my desktop that has the issue. Recently, I made a change to the "execution policy" while following some youtube video in attempt to debug a different problem, until this one showed up. My version of python in my base is 3.9.7, but I'm using a virtual environment and the python version in that is 3.9.13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error could be caused by having the file open somehow. Did you run it already and tried running it again? Then the file is open, and you are trying to write the data to the same object, which is locked while open. In that case, close the file/tab and run it again.

Not sure why you are using the offline mode explicitly, or why you assign a filename when not saving it. PLotly > 4.0 is offline only.
I would use this code instead:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

np.random.seed(42)

random_x = np.random.randint(1,101,100)
random_y = np.random.randint(1,101,100)

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=random_x, y=random_y, mode='markers'))

fig.show()
```

Comment: This works! however, since I'm following a MOOC, I'm trying not to deviate too much from it. Now that you mention it, it may be b/c my plotly version is of a more recent release compared to the one in the MOOC (the course came out in 2019).